# Odin project's task to make a function 'capitalize' and I have no idea if my answer is any good?

Tags: javascript, function

So I've been doing the Odin Project and I'm at functions right now and there's a task "Write a function called capitalize that takes a string and returns that string with only the first letter capitalized. Make sure that it can take strings that are lowercase, UPPERCASE or BoTh."

```html
<script>
     

     function capitalize(myName, myNameUpper, myNameRan) {
     const toUpper = "Bartek";
     myName = "bartek";
     myNameUpper = "BARTEK";
     myNameRan = "BaRtEk";
     myName, myNameUpper, myNameRan = toUpper;
     console.log(myName, myNameUpper, myNameRan)
     
     }

     capitalize();
    
    
     
      </script>
```

Is my function any good? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Since it doesn’t “*return [the] string with only the first letter capitalized*” I’d suggest it doesn’t meet the stated requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
     

     function capitalize(lowercase,uppercase,both ) {
     const capitalizeLower = lowercase.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowercase.slice(1).toLowerCase();
     const capitalizeUpper = uppercase.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + uppercase.slice(1).toLowerCase();
     const capitalizeBoth = both.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + both.slice(1).toLowerCase();
     console.log(capitalizeLower, capitalizeUpper , capitalizeBoth)
     return `${capitalizeLower} ${capitalizeUpper} ${capitalizeBoth}`
     }

     capitalize("hello","HELLO","hEllO");
    
    
     
      </script>
```